# Custom queries in Mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Is it possible to pass custom javascript to Mongoid sort of like find_by_sql or update_all in active record?

The particular case I'm thinking of is I would like to `inc` a field on a bunch of documents matching a criteria.

It looks like this is possible in MongoDB:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-ModifierOperations

```
db.people.update( { name:"Joe" }, { $inc: { created_at : -1 } } );
```

But I don't thing Mongoid allows it (it seems to only let you inc one document at a time).  And their `update_all` method I believe only can use $set.  Thanks!
http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/modification.html

For example, this doesn't work

```
User.where(:name => "Joe").update_all("{ $inc: { created_at : -1 } }")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoid offers a [Model#inc](http://mongoid.org/docs/persistence/atomic.html#inc) method but it's an instance method, not a class method.

However, by reading the source code of the `Model.update_all` method it turns out you can easily create your own `inc` class method.

```
def update_all(attributes = {})
  klass.collection.update(
    selector,
    { "$set" => attributes },
    Safety.merge_safety_options(:multi => true)
  ).tap do
    Threaded.clear_safety_options!
  end
end
```

As you can see, Mongoid is passing the query to the underlying mongodb driver.
The following method should work

```
class User
  def self.inc(field, value)
    klass.collection.update(
      selector,
      { "$inc" => { field => value } },
      Safety.merge_safety_options(:multi => true)
    ).tap do
      Threaded.clear_safety_options!
    end
  end
end
```

Please note I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: This solution worked great!  Thanks Simone.  Much appreciated.  I could see this being added to Mongoid in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

What about multi flag  specifier in update command

As per the [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating),

> db.collection.update( criteria, objNew, upsert, multi )
>
> multi - indicates if all documents matching criteria should be updated
> rather than just one. Can be useful with the $ operators below.

so set multi flag true in your update command

```
db.people.update( { name:"Joe" }, { $inc: { created_at : -1 } },false,true );
```